# How to Pan with left mouse click in qgis programmatically?

Tags: qgis, python, mapping

How can I pan my map on Qgis with left mouse button programmatically ? I see the desktop application do this, so no mouse middle button !

Comment: Gradual panning over time, or instantaneously pan to a specific location?

Comment: Qgis uses wheel button press, to do pan, I want to press left button instead using python code.

Answer (score 1):

You can 'click' the Pan button like so:

```py
for child in iface.mainWindow().children():
    if child.objectName() == 'mActionPan':
        child.trigger()
        break
```

This will activate the panning tool, which responds to the left mouse button.